# Can I add a entry table in my react component using svg Having a scroll bar and 0 to 20 indexes all empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I want to add entry tables in my website using svg. The tables are named top and bottom and have a scroll bar inside them. Entry Indexes are 1 to 20 having 1 index on one line. 2 is the minimum index number, which tables can show in start. The table is followed by a button with counter on I want that when user selects his counts (max count is 20 and minimum is 2) the tables updates his index value according to the count.

I tried and built entry tables using svg but I am finding difficulty in adding the scroll bar inside, showing indexes and updating Indexes according to count

Comment: Best if you show use the code markup you have so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.